# Handy Hints for Committing to the Beta

Tags: discussion, private-beta

Feel free to add any other ideas to increase the likelihood of following through on beta commitment - because if all 200+ committers follow through then we'll fly through this beta stage with ease.

Answer (score 11):

1. Edit your stack exchange drop down to include the new *economics* beta at the top so you remember it every time you navigate between stacks. By default the list is sorted by stacks with your highest reputation.
2. If you have an interesting idea for a question but you don't think you'll be able to ask it with the economics nomenclature and post quality we want in the private beta - maybe ask someone on meta for help?
3. Trawl through other forums for decent but abused questions worth salvaging. You'll need to use your own words in order to meet [**cc-by-sa**](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) requirements.
4. Lock in a block of time on your calendar app to engage the economics beta without distraction. This will make commitment much more likely and with highest quality of posting.
5. **Have fun!** *No fun = No play. No play = No beta.* I'm sure I'm not the only one to feel that a fresh private beta is like unwrapping an early Christmas present.